# Computer B and C can ping A, but A can't ping B or C

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, ping

I'm a bit new to networking and I have the following Problem:

*I have three computers:*

```
A (windows10)
B (windows10)
C (ubuntu server, raspberry)
```

*If I run the ping command:*

```
A to B -> Request timed out.

A to C -> Destination host unreachable.

B to A -> works.

B to C -> works.

C to A -> works.

C to B -> works.
```

All computers are connected to the same modem via ethernet cables. The weird part is, that the connection from A to B and C worked yesterday but not anymore.. If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Make sure Network Discovery and Private (not Public) networking is enabled on all computers.

Comment: Try to disable temporarily the firewall on A, also to reset (turn off/on) the modem/router. What happened on A yesterday (perhaps Windows Update)?

Comment: Also any changes to Advanced Networking and Sharing (Network Discovery) requires restart if changed.

Comment: @John Network Discovery and Private networking was already enabled :/

Comment: @harrymc disabling the firewall and turning the modem on and off didn't help..

Comment: I don't know if it's useful, but the message "Destination host unreachable" is a "reply" from the ipv4 of computer A, pinging to this IP from A works. (-> pinging from A to A works, I don't think that helps xD)

Comment: Is the network on A defined as PRIVATE? If there is no explanation and you have System Restore enabled, rollback Windows to before this happened.

Comment: Try enabling ping in computer B group policy ..... https://thesysadminchannel.com/how-to-enable-ping-using-group-policy-gpo/

Comment: @harrymc, yes the network on A is private.

Comment: @John I don't think enabling ping in computer B group policy would help, the ping is just for testing, the main problem is that I want to connect from A to C via ssh, but it's currently not working anymore.  The only thing I know is that there's something wrong with A or the modem because I can connect from b to C via ssh.

Comment: More in the line of a guess - was SMBv1 being used and then disabled in a Windows Update?

Comment: @John I just checked my update history and the only update that happened lately was [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/definitions/antimalware-definition-release-notes?requestVersion=1.353.818.0)

Comment: @John SMBv1 was disabled, I just enabled it manually, but it's still not working..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @kamil I agree, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The problem got magically fixed overnight.

Thanks to everyone who gave me advice!